# Getting (insecure_transport) OAuth 2 MUST utilize https with CERT managed by Heroku. I have a subdomain attached pointed to Server

Tags: ssl, heroku, heroku-ssl

I'm trying to user google sheets API service, which requires an HTTPS connection. I'm getting the following error

```
Exception Type: InsecureTransportError at my_site/google/success/
Exception Value: (insecure_transport) OAuth 2 MUST utilize https.
```

I am using Heroku, and on my settings it says `AMC Status: ok`. I verified that I'm using HTTPS by running `curl -vI https://my_site/google/success` 
which returned:

```
SSL certificate verify ok
```

From my perspective it seems that I am using HTTPS, but I am getting this error. What could I be doing wrong? Surely I have something misconfigured Anything else I need to provide from troubleshooting? Here is the Full traceback:

```
    traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/app/google_api/views.py", line 56, in authorize_success
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=code)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 286, in fetch_token
    return self.oauth2session.fetch_token(self.client_config["token_uri"], **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 239, in fetch_token
    self._client.parse_request_uri_response(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/web_application.py", line 203, in parse_request_uri_response
    response = parse_authorization_code_response(uri, state=state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 256, in parse_authorization_code_response
    raise InsecureTransportError()
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
import os 
os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
```